# how can I position image like this?

Tags: html, css, position

How can I position images like in the example below

[image]

I've tried different things, but I cannot reach the result I need.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can we see your attempts anyway in a fiddle?

Comment: You could create a div with a position of relative and then another div inside it with a position of absolute. then you can center it inside that div using things like: top: 50px; left:50px; it depends on how big your parent div is.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a single `div` and create the outer circles via `box-shadow` property (since they have no content inside) , e.g.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxjjXW

**Markup**

```
<div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  border: 85px green solid;
  box-shadow: -100px -100px 0 brown, 
              100px -100px 0 lightgray, 
              -100px 100px 0 red, 
              100px 100px 0 blue; 
}
```

---

**Final result**

[image]

Comment: you're welcome @AnastasijaScepak - if this answer was useful to you you may mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

I would use css classes with the position attribute.

W3schools.com: 
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Example:

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```